# How to apply the example of cars passing through a road to the Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Cars pass through a road junction according to a Poisson distribution.
>   An average of 5 cars per minute pass through the junction.
>
> a) What is the probability that exactly one car passes through the
>   junction in a certain minute?
>
> b) What is the expected number of cars to pass through in three
>   minutes?
>
> c) What is the probability that exactly the expected number from (b)
>   pass through in a certain three minute period?

I used the formula $f(x,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$

For part a $f(1,5) = \frac{5 e^{-5}}{1!} = 0.0337$.....

For part b) $\lambda = 5$ for one minute, so $\lambda = 5 \cdot 3 = 15$ for 3 minute

For part c) $f(15,15) = \frac{15^{15} e^{-15}]}{15!} = 0.10244$...

Is my method and the answers correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think your answers are all right.